# Question about notation in change of basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

> for matrix $A$ and ordered basis $\beta$, find $[L_A]_\beta$.

$$A= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 \\  1 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix} $$

$$\beta=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\  1 \\ \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\  -1 \\ \end{pmatrix} \right\}$$

I don't get the notation sign meaning of this $[L_A]_\beta$. I know $[L_A]$ is the left multiplication, and $[L_A]_\beta$ is the vector coordinate of the left multiplication? It doesn't make sense to me literally. (I just want to understand this conceptual question, then I can try solving by myself.)

Comment: I think they want you to find the matrix for the linear transformation, which is represented by matrix $A$ with respect to the standard basis, with respect to basis $\beta$

Comment: Note standard MathJax usage, as in my edit to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\textsf{L}_A$ is the linear function that maps $\mathbb{R}^{2\times1}$ into itself by the rule
$$\textsf{L}_A \begin{pmatrix} x\\y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1&3\\1&1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x\\y \end{pmatrix}$$
and the notation $[\textsf{L}_A]_\beta$ means that $[\textsf{L}_A]_\beta^\beta$, that is, the matrix representation of $\textsf{L}_A$ with respect to the basis $\beta$. All you need is to find
$$\textsf{L}_A \begin{pmatrix} 1\\1 \end{pmatrix} 
\quad \textrm{ and } \quad
\textsf{L}_A \begin{pmatrix} 1\\-1 \end{pmatrix}$$
and write each of them as a linear combination of the same basis vectors. Finally, put the coefficients that you obtained previously in a $2\times2$ matrix and you call it $[\textsf{L}_A]_\beta$.